# ActiveMerchant's support for determining the account status (verified/unverified) of a PayPal Express Checkout customer/buyer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal, activemerchant

I am currently working on a Ruby-on-Rails web-application that accepts PayPal payments through PayPal's Express Checkout and ActiveMerchant. I have done several research on ActiveMerchant's support for determining if a customer/buyer has paid using either a verified or unverified PayPal account but I got no luck on finding a helpful guide.

I find it also that ActiveMerchant is currently not well-documented so it's not that helpful at all.

Below are the relevant codes that my project is currently using. On PaymentsController#purchase, I temporarily used the `#params['protection_eligibility']` and the `#params['protection_eligibility_type']` methods of the `ActiveMerchant::Billing::PaypalExpressResponse` object that is returned by the EXPRESS_GATEWAY.purchase method call, to assess if a PayPal customer/buyer has a verified/unverified PayPal account. Later I found out that this is not a reliable basis for knowing the customer's account status.

I hope somebody can give me a wisdom on knowing whether a PayPal customer/buyer has a verified/unverified account using Ruby-on-Rails' ActiveMerchant or using other alternatives on Rails.

```rb
# config/environments/development.rb
config.after_initialize do
  ActiveMerchant::Billing::Base.mode = :test
  paypal_options = {
      # credentials removed for this StackOverflow question
      :login => "",
      :password => "",
      :signature => ""
  }
  ::EXPRESS_GATEWAY = ActiveMerchant::Billing::PaypalExpressGateway.new(paypal_options)
end

# app/models/payment.rb
class Payment < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...
  PAYPAL_CREDIT_TO_PRICE = {
      # prices in cents(US)
      1  =>  75_00,
      4  => 200_00,
      12 => 550_00
  }
  STATUSES  = ["pending", "complete", "failed"]
  TYPES     = ["paypal", "paypal-verified", "paypal-unverified", "wiretransfer", "creditcard"]
  # ...
end

# app/controllers/payments_controller.rb
class PaymentsController < ApplicationController
  # ...
  def checkout
    session[:credits_qty] = params[:credit_qty].to_i

    total_as_cents = Payment::PAYPAL_CREDIT_TO_PRICE[session[:credits_qty]]
    setup_purchase_params = {
        :allow_guest_checkout => true,
        :ip => request.remote_ip,
        :return_url => url_for(:action => 'purchase', :only_path => false),
        :cancel_return_url => url_for(:controller => 'payments', :action => 'new', :only_path => false),
        :items => [{
                       :name => pluralize(session[:credits_qty], "Credit"),
                       :number => 1,
                       :quantity => 1,
                       :amount => Payment::PAYPAL_CREDIT_TO_PRICE[session[:credits_qty]]
                   }]
    }

    setup_response = EXPRESS_GATEWAY.setup_purchase(total_as_cents, setup_purchase_params)
    redirect_to EXPRESS_GATEWAY.redirect_url_for(setup_response.token)
  end

  def purchase
    if params[:token].nil? or params[:PayerID].nil?
      redirect_to new_payment_url, :notice => I18n.t('flash.payment.paypal.error')
      return
    end

    total_as_cents = Payment::PAYPAL_CREDIT_TO_PRICE[session[:credits_qty]]
    purchase_params = {
        :ip => request.remote_ip,
        :token => params[:token],
        :payer_id => params[:PayerID],
        :items =>  [{
                        :name => pluralize(session[:credits_qty], "Credit"),
                        :number => 1,
                        :quantity => 1,
                        :amount => Payment::PAYPAL_CREDIT_TO_PRICE[session[:credits_qty]]
                    }]
    }

    purchase = EXPRESS_GATEWAY.purchase total_as_cents, purchase_params
    if purchase.success?
      payment = current_user.payments.new
      payment.paypal_params = params
      payment.credits = session[:credits_qty]
      payment.amount  = Payment::PAYPAL_CREDIT_TO_PRICE[session[:credits_qty]]
      payment.currency = "USD"
      payment.status = "complete"
      if(purchase.params["receipt_id"] && (purchase.params["success_page_redirect_requested"] == "true"))
        payment.payment_type = "creditcard"
      else
        if purchase.params['protection_eligibility'] == 'Eligible' && purchase.params['protection_eligibility_type'] == 'ItemNotReceivedEligible,UnauthorizedPaymentEligible'
          payment.payment_type = 'paypal-verified'
        else
          payment.payment_type = 'paypal-unverified'
        end
      end
      payment.ip_address = request.remote_ip.to_s
      payment.save!

      SiteMailer.paypal_payment(payment).deliver
      SiteMailer.notice_payment(payment).deliver

      notice = I18n.t('flash.payment.status.thanks')
      redirect_to profile_url, :notice => notice
    else
      notice = I18n.t('flash.payment.status.failed', :message => purchase.message)
      redirect_to new_payment_url, :notice => notice
    end
  end
  # ...
end
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Hello Beerlington, my question is, does ActiveMerchant has a functionality for indicating that a PayPal Express Checout payment is done by an verified/unverified PayPal account?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used PayPal's paypal-sdk-merchant gem to do the job ActiveMerchant wasn't able to help me with (getting the status of a payer's account: verified/unverified PayPal account. I followed the installation of paypal-sdk-merchant on https://github.com/paypal/merchant-sdk-ruby

- gem 'paypal-sdk-merchant'
- bundle install
- rails generate paypal:sdk:install

Then I set-up their samples https://github.com/paypal/merchant-sdk-ruby#samples. After setting-up the samples, go to /samples of your Rails app and you will find a lot of code generator for what ever function you need from PayPal's API. Don't forget to configure your config/paypal.yml. I configured the username, password and signature (can be obtained from your PayPal sandbox specifically your test seller account) and removed the app_id in my case.

I obtained the following code for getting a PayPal payer's account status (verified/unverified) using PayPal's samples (/samples) and placed it on a class method of a model in my app:

```
def self.get_paypal_payer_status(transaction_id)
  require 'paypal-sdk-merchant'
  api = PayPal::SDK::Merchant::API.new

  get_transaction_details = api.build_get_transaction_details({
    :Version => "94.0",
    :TransactionID => transaction_id
  })
  get_transaction_details_response = api.get_transaction_details(get_transaction_details)

  get_transaction_details_response.payment_transaction_details.payer_info.payer_status
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with ActiveMerchant so I can't tell you specific to that, but with any Express Checkout implementation you can use [GetExpressCheckoutDetails](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/api/getexpresscheckoutdetails-api-operation-nvp) to obtain the payers information which will include a PAYERSTATUS parameter with a value of "verified" or "unverified".

It's an optional call, but I would assume ActiveMerchant is probably including it so you just need to track that down and pull that parameter accordingly.

Alternatively, you can use [Instant Payment Notification (IPN)](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro) to receive transaction information and you will get back a payer_status parameter here as well.

Comment: Hello Andrew, your answer have lead me to dig more on PayPal's Developer page and there I found their so-called New PayPal SDKs and from there, I learned about PayPal's paypal-sdk-merchant gem which had helped do the job that ActiveMerchant was not able to help me. Thanks for your lead!